# Playing raw audio file in default music player

Tags: android, android-intent, android-music-player

My App is having audio files in raw folder. Now whenever app gets launched these audio files should play using default music player. I tried below code App is crashing with "No Activity found to handle this intent".

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("companion.harman.com.ceshuclient/res/raw/fav.mp3"), "audio/*");
 startActivity(intent);
```

The same audio files can be played using "MediaPlayer" object but that is not what exactly I'm trying to acheive.

Any sample code or links can be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The fav.mp3 was not saved in External Storage Directory, then only your app can see he.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following (Where mp3file is the name of the file in the raw folder without extension. Use only lowercase characters, please):

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer(this,R.raw.mp3file);

player.prepare();
player.start();
```

```
player.stop();
player.reset();
player.release();
player = null;
```

Here is the link of demo source code to [play mp3 File](https://jmsliu.com/2499/play-mp3-in-android-tutorial-android-mediaplayer-example.html)

Comment: Hi mdroid Thanks for your time and  response. I clearly mentioned in the question that this will work fine. But I'm looking to launch default music player.